# Can someone tell me why garbage is being printed from the my linked list?

Tags: c++, linked-list

So I am working on this project for school. I have everything working. i constructed the linked list first and in the code you can see that it takes everything fine and prints it out. When I try to use the menu to insert items into the list it seems to work. I have put several printouts to see whats going on. When I print the list only the items imputed by the menu come out corrupted.

I have looked at several post which indicate the same sort of problem but I do not see where in my code the problem may lay.

Can you guys look through the functions and see if I am doing something wrong. I far as I can see it all seems to work yet the output is full of garbage. 
Thanks for the help
here is the code for the project

Word.h

```
class Word
{

public:
    void SetEnglish(char *word);
    char *GetEnglish();
    void SetFinnish(char *word);
    char *GetFinnish();
    void SetPrev(Word *word);
    Word *GetPrev();
    void SetNext(Word *word);
    Word *GetNext();

private:
    char *English;
    char *Finnish;
    Word *prev;          //pointer to previous node 
    Word *next;          //pointer to next node 


};

class dlist
{
public:

    Word *front;       //pointer to front of list   
    Word *back;        //pointer to back of list  

dlist()
{
    front=NULL;
    back=NULL;
}

void insertFront(char *Eng, char *Fin);             
int insertBack(char *Eng, char *Fin);
void insertBefore(char *Eng, char *Fin, Word *nodeB);
void insertAfter(char *Eng, char *Fin, Word *nodeA);
void printDListFront();

};
```

Word.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Word.h"

#define Word_OK (0)

using namespace std;

//sets the English word
void Word::SetEnglish(char *Eng)
{
    English = Eng;
}

//gets the English word
char *Word::GetEnglish()
{
    return English;
}

//sets the Finnish word
void Word::SetFinnish(char *Fin)
{
    Finnish = Fin;
}

//gets the Finnish word
char *Word::GetFinnish()
{
    return Finnish;
}

//sets the previous node
void Word::SetPrev(Word *node)
{
    prev = node;
}

//gets the previous node
Word *Word::GetPrev()
{
    return prev;
}

//sets the next node
void Word::SetNext(Word *node)
{
    next = node;
}

//gets the next node
Word *Word::GetNext()
{
    return next;
}

//insert a node after the last node 
int dlist::insertBack (char *Eng, char *Fin)
{          
    cout << "English: " << Eng << " " << "Finnish :" << Fin << "\n";
    if(this->back==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"insert at back";
        insertFront(Eng, Fin);
    }
    else
    {
        cout<<"insert at back";
        insertAfter(Eng, Fin, this->back  );
    }

    return Word_OK;
}

//insert a node before the front node 
void dlist::insertFront (char *Eng, char *Fin)
    {
    Word *newNode;
    if(this->front==NULL)
    {
        newNode=new Word();
        this->front=newNode;
        this->back =newNode;
        newNode->SetPrev(NULL);
        newNode->SetNext(NULL);
        newNode->SetEnglish(Eng);
        newNode->SetFinnish(Fin);
    }
    else
    {
        insertBefore(Eng, Fin, this->front );
    }
}

//insert a node after  nodeB
void dlist::insertAfter(char *Eng, char *Fin, Word *nodeB)
{
    cout << "\nEnglish1: " << Eng << " " << "Finnish1: " << Fin << "\n";
    Word *newNode;
    newNode=new Word();
    newNode->SetNext(nodeB->GetNext()) ;
    newNode->SetPrev(nodeB);
    newNode->SetEnglish(Eng);
    newNode->SetFinnish(Fin);

    if(nodeB->GetNext()==NULL)
    {
        cout<<"\n "<< endl;
        this->back =newNode; 
    }
    nodeB->SetNext(newNode);
    cout<<"2"<<endl;
}

//insert a node before nodeB
void dlist::insertBefore(char *Eng, char *Fin, Word *nodeB)    
{
    Word *newNode;
    newNode=new Word();
    newNode->SetPrev(nodeB->GetPrev());
    newNode->SetNext(nodeB);
    newNode->SetEnglish(Eng); 
    newNode->SetFinnish(Fin); 
    if(nodeB->GetPrev()==NULL)
    {
        this->front=newNode; 
    }
    nodeB->SetPrev(newNode);

}


//Print the list from front 
void dlist::printDListFront()
{
    Word* curr2;
    curr2= this->front;
    cout<<"\n------------------------\n";
    cout<<"Words in the Dictionary: \n";
    cout<<"------------------------\n";

    while(curr2!=NULL)
    {
        cout<<curr2->GetEnglish();
        cout<<" "<< curr2->GetFinnish()<<"\n";
        curr2=curr2->GetNext();
    }
    cout<<endl;
}// print the Double Linked List from front
```

main.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include "menu.h"
#include "Word.h"

using namespace std;

#define Word_OK (0)
#define Word_Not_Found (-1)
#define Word_already_Exist (-2)
#define Word_too_big (-3)
#define Dictionary_empty (-4)
#define File_error (-5)
#define Memory_error (-6)
#define Word_Unknown_Error (-20)
#define Buffer (200)
#define Max_len (30)
#define FILE_NAME "dictionary.txt"

/* Search the word in the list and print it if found. 
   return an error code if not found or the dictionary is empty. */
int SearchWord();
/* Add a word in the list from user input.
   return an error code if the word already exist or if input is too long. */
int InsertWord(dlist *w);
/* Function used by InsertWord() and InitDictionary() to insert a new word in 
   the list at right position (order alphabetically by english word).
   return an error code if there is a memory allocation problem. */
int chainWord(char *en, char *fi, Word *w);
/* Remove a word from the list.
   return an error code if word not found. */
int DeleteWord();
/* Show all the words in the dictionary. This was first a debug function; but
   since it works, I kept it. Considere that as an extra feature.
   return an error code if the dictionnary is empty. */
int ShowAllWord(dlist *list);
/* Print error if something goes wrong. */
void PrintError(int aErrorCode);
/* Read the saved words from the file and load it to the dictionary.
   return an error code if it don't manage to open the file. */
int InitDictionary(dlist *list);
/* Save the words in the file and clean the memory before leaving the program.
   return an error code if there is a problem with the file. */
int ExitDictionary();
int putDictionary(Word *w);

void putword(dlist *st)
{
    char eng[30], fin[30];
    cout << "English word: " ;
    cin >> eng;
    cout << "Finnish word: ";
    cin >> fin;
    st->insertBack(eng, fin);
}

void main()
{
    char eng[30], fin[30];

    dlist *st ;
    st= new dlist();
    cout << "English word: " ;
    cin >> eng;
    cout << "Finnish word: ";
    cin >> fin;
    st->insertBack(eng, fin); 
    st->insertBack("hello", "hei"); 
    st->insertBack("we", "me"); 
    st->insertBack("they", "he"); 
    st->insertBack("truck", "rekka") ;
    st->printDListFront ();

    Menu m;
    m.PrintHeader();
    m.PrintMenu();
    //PrintError(InitDictionary(st));
    int errorcode = 0;
    char c;
    cout << "Choose option: ";
    cin >> c;
    fflush(stdin); //I want one option at the time, so flush the end of line
    while(c != 'e' && c != 'E'){
        switch(c){
            case 's':
            case 'S':
               //  errorcode = SearchWord();
                 break;
            case 'i':
            case 'I':
                  putword(st);
                 break;
            case 'd':
            case 'D':
               //  errorcode = DeleteWord();
                 break;
            case 'a':
            case 'A':
               errorcode = ShowAllWord(st);
                 break;
            default:
                 system("cls");
                 m.PrintMenu();
        }
        PrintError(errorcode);
        cout << "Choose option: ";
        cin >> c;
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    //PrintError(ExitDictionary());


    system("pause");
}


int InsertWord(dlist *list)
{
    char eng[30], fin[30];

    cout << "English word: " ;
    cin >> eng;
    cout << "Finnish word: ";
    cin >> fin;

    int res = list->insertBack(eng, fin);

    return res;
}

int ShowAllWord(dlist *list)
{
    list->printDListFront ();
    return 0;
}

void PrintError(int aErrorCode){
     switch(aErrorCode){
         case Word_OK:
            break;
         case Word_Not_Found:
            cout << "Word not found!" << endl;
            break;
         case Word_already_Exist:
            cout << "The word already exist!" << endl;
            break;
         case Word_too_big:
            cout << "The word is too big!" << endl;
            break;
         case Dictionary_empty:
            cout << "Dictionary is empty!" << endl;
            break;
         case File_error:
            cout << "Error with file!" << endl;
            break;
         case Memory_error:
            cout << "Memory allocation problem!" << endl;
            break;
         case Word_Unknown_Error:
         default:
            cout << "Oppps Unknown Error!" << endl;
            break;
     }                       
}
```

menu.h

```
#ifndef _MENU_H_
#define _MENU_H_

//this class was created as an exercise and also to reduce the size of code of
//the main.
class Menu{
    public:
       /*print the information about the program and the author.*/
       void PrintHeader();
       /*print the options for the user.*/
       void PrintMenu();
};

#endif
```

menu.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include "menu.h"

using namespace std;
/* Implementation of the menu class. */
void Menu::PrintHeader(){
     cout << "*************************************" << endl
          << "****      Dictionary             ****" << endl
          << "****      By Your Name and ID    ****" << endl;
}

void Menu::PrintMenu(){
     cout << "*************************************" << endl
          << "***             MENU              ***" << endl
          << "*************************************" << endl
          << "S - Search"         << endl
          << "I - Insert"         << endl
          << "D - Delete"         << endl
          << "A - Show all words" << endl
          << "E - Exit"           << endl
          << "  - Any other key to clear the screen" << endl
          << "*************************************" << endl;
}
```

Comment: Explain what you mean by "full of garbage".

Comment: You're problem appears to be that you're using automatic arrays that are going out of scope and getting reused instead of mallocing or newing space that stays around.

Comment: It looks like you're using `char*` where you mean `std::string&`.

Comment: Asking strangers to spot errors in your code by inspection is not productive.  You should identify (or at least isolate) the problem by using a debugger or print statements, and then come back with a more specific question (once you've narrowed it down to a 10-line [test-case](http://sscce.org)).

Answer (score 1):

```
char eng[30], fin[30];

cout << "English word: " ;
cin >> eng;
cout << "Finnish word: ";
cin >> fin;

int res = list->insertBack(eng, fin);
```

You use local arrays for insertBack argument, and also the Word class holds pointer to them. They'll go out of scope once the function terminates and the value could be anything after that. What you should store in the Word class is the **copy** of the string, in its own storage (either dynamically or statically).

Comment: Like using `std::string` that handles all this automatically.

Comment: So let me see if I follow what your saying. I understand about the local usage but not sure what you mean a copy of the string in the class. So in my class should it be like string English; and string Finnish; instead of chat *English?

Comment: @Xintaris - Yes, a `std::string` stores the words for you, and takes care of copying itself when needed. You might want to use `std::string` as the parameter type as well. A `char*` just points to another place where the text is supposed to be. In your case, the word isn't there any longer when you try to print it. That is one of the dangers of using pointers - suddenly the thing they are pointing to might not be there anymore.

Comment: Great thanks that worked like a charm. Now on to building the search and delete functions. Thanks for your help.